# No access token in .kube/config

Tags: kubernetes, gcloud, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-security

After upgrading my cluster in GKE the dashboard will no longer accept certificate authentication.

No problem there's a token available in the .kube/config says my colleague

```
  user:
    auth-provider:
      config:
        access-token: REDACTED
        cmd-args: config config-helper --format=json
        cmd-path: /home/user/workspace/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud
        expiry: 2018-01-09T08:59:18Z
        expiry-key: '{.credential.token_expiry}'
        token-key: '{.credential.access_token}'
      name: gcp
```

Except in my case there isn't...

```
  user:
    auth-provider:
      config:
        cmd-args: config config-helper --format=json
        cmd-path: /home/user/Dev/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud
        expiry-key: '{.credential.token_expiry}'
        token-key: '{.credential.access_token}'
      name: gcp
```

I've tried re-authenticating with gcloud, comparing gcloud settings with colleagues, updating gcloud, re-installing gcloud, checking permissions in Cloud Platform. Pretty much everything I can think of, by still no access token will be generated.

Can anyone help please?!

```
 $ gcloud container clusters get-credentials cluster-3 --zone xxx --project xxx                            
Fetching cluster endpoint and auth data.
kubeconfig entry generated for cluster-3.

$ gcloud config list                                                                                                    
[core]
account = xxx
disable_usage_reporting = False
project = xxx

Your active configuration is: [default]

$ kubectl version                                                                                                                    
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"8", GitVersion:"v1.8.4"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, very annoying and silly answer - you have to make any request using kubectl for the token to be generated and saved into the kubeconfig file.

Comment: Is there a way to circumvent this? Can i somehow get the access token in the config file without making a request from kubectl?

Comment: So, do a `use-context` with `kubectl` and then a `kubectl get namespaces`? I need to switch context because, well, I have to use multiple clusters.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned you "updated your cluster in GKE" - I'm sure what you actually did, so I'm interpreting it as generating a new cluster. There are two things to insure that you didn't appear to cover in your problem statement - one is that kubectl is enabled and two is that you can actually generate a new kubeconfig file (you could easily be referring to the older ~/.kube/conf from the prior-to-the-updated cluster in GKE). Therefore, doing these commands insures you have the correct authentication required and that token should become available:

    `$ gcloud components install kubectl
    $ gcloud container clusters create <cluster-name>
    $ gcloud container clusters get-credentials <cluster-name>`

Then...Generate the kubeconfig file (assuming you have a running cluster on GCP **and a service account configured for the project/GKE**, have run `kubectl proxy`, etc.):
`$ gcloud container clusters get-credentials <cluster_id>`

This will create a ${HOME}/.kube/config file which has the token in it. Inspect the config file and you'll see the token value:
`$ cat ~/.kube/config`
OR
`$ kubectl config view` will display it to the screen...

`...
users:
- name: gke_<project_id><zone><cluster_id>
  user:
    auth-provider:
      config:
        access-token: **<COPY_THIS_TOKEN>**
        cmd-args: config config-helper --format=json
        cmd-path: ...path-to.../google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud
        expiry: 2018-04-13T23:11:15Z
        expiry-key: '{.credential.token_expiry}'
        token-key: '{.credential.access_token}'
      name: gcp`

With that token copied, go back to http://localhost:8001/ and select "token", then paste the token value there...good to go

Comment: Hmm, you've pretty much just repeated the information in the question here.

Comment: I edited the response, hopefully that helps - if you can generate creds from the command line and have kubectl working, this answer should get you there.