# gcloud does not add access token for connecting to GKE cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, kubeconfig

I created a GKE cluster and to connect to it with `kubectl` ran the command that appears when clicked on Connect button against my cluster.

```sh
gcloud container clusters get-credentials cluster-name --zone us-central1-a --project project-id
```

In `$HOME/.kube/config` I see entries as below:

```
- name: cluster-name
  user:
    auth-provider:
      config:
        cmd-args: config config-helper --format=json
        cmd-path: /usr/lib64/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud
        expiry-key: '{.credential.token_expiry}'
        token-key: '{.credential.access_token}'
      name: gcp
```

To add a new namespace, I did the following:

```sh
kubectl config use-context cluster-name
kubectl create namespace demo
```

This results in error:

```sh
error: No Auth Provider found for name "gcp"
```

I repeated the step of adding the credentials in the Google Cloud shell. There, I am able to create a new namespace successfully. I noticed that, the `access-token` and `expiry` fields are visible.

```
auth-provider:
      config:
        access-token: omitted
        cmd-args: config config-helper --format=json
        cmd-path: /google/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud
        expiry: "2019-12-10T03:39:53Z"
        expiry-key: '{.credential.token_expiry}'
        token-key: '{.credential.access_token}'
      name: gcp
```

Therefore, how do I get the `gcloud containers cluster get-credentials` command to update my `kubeconfig` correctly?

Comment: Is there any reason you ran `kubectl config use-context cluster-name` command? It is not clear what's your problem, and what are you trying to do.

Comment: Where did you run these commands? In your local terminal? Did you run `gcloud auth login` to authenticate before you ran `gcloud container clusters get-credentials`?

Comment: Yes, the commands were run on my local terminal. Yes, `gcloud auth login` was run before getting credentials.

Comment: Most likely something went wrong with 'gcloud container clusters get-credentials', could you add the ['--verbosity="debug"' flag](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/#--verbosity) to the command and share the output of it?

Comment: Ok. In the meatime, found this one similar to issue I am facing. I am not sure, I follow the answer though - https://stackoverflow.com/a/48182401/919480

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this exact problem, and it turned out my client was out of date.  Running v1.11 for the client and my cluster was 1.15+ gave me the `no auth provider` error.

Followed the instructions [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/) to get up to client v1.18 and solved my issue.