# I was failed to "bazel build" in step which is inside "Deploy Cloud Robotics Core from sources" page in googlecloudrobotics/core

Tags: google-cloud-platform, build, cloud, bazel, google-cloud-robotics

I am working on setting up cloud side in google cloud platform to make environment google cloud robotics. so to speak, I am working in cloud shell in google cloud platform.
you can find that in https://googlecloudrobotics.github.io/core/how-to/deploy-from-sources.

but I was failed to "bazel build" in step4  which is inside "Deploy Cloud Robotics Core from sources" in "Build and deploy the project".

the below is part of Error message.

> >
>   xxxx@cloudshell:~/core (mystical-app-257114)$  bazel build //...
>   Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
>   INFO: Call stack for the definition of repository 'ros_adapter_deps' which is a pip_import (rule definition at /home/xxxx/.cache/bazel/_bazel_xxxx/5b4f6a6ed94b6afc2c6cb5d52170621a/external/io_bazel_rules_python/python/pip.bzl:42:14):
>    - /home/xxxxx/core/WORKSPACE:156:1
>   ERROR: An error occurred during the fetch of repository 'ros_adapter_deps':
>      Traceback (most recent call last):
>   <<

Is anybody help me for this ?

Thanks in advance for reading

Comment: There should have been output following the "Traceback (most recent call last): <<" which actually describes what happened. The output you provided only states that something went wrong but not what

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Shell isn't able to build Cloud Robotics Core from source because of the 5GB disk limit. You have a couple of options:

- Use the binary install instead of building from source: https://googlecloudrobotics.github.io/core/quickstart.html
- Run the build in an environment with more disk space (I'd suggest at least 10GB), such as a new VM instance: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance

(I'm not 100% sure this is the error you encountered, because your question doesn't include the full traceback, but when I tried to run the build on Cloud Shell I ran into "No space left on device" errors)

Comment: I changed a environ. into my ubuntu18.04 desktop but I faced the other issue. plz read the last line of below log.
>>>
Outputs:
<skipped>
kubeconfig entry generated for cloud-robotics.
error: No Auth Provider found for name "gcp"
Generating RSA private key, 2048 bit long modulus (2 primes)

e is 65537 (0x010001)
Can't load /home/gusewan/.rnd into RNG
139908924200768:error:2406F079:random number generator:RAND_load_file:Cannot open file:../crypto/rand/randfile.c:88:Filename=/home/gusewan/.rnd
Initialized successfully
synk init done
error: No Auth Provider found for name "gcp"
<<<

Comment: I've never see the error about the RNG before, hopefully it's not fatal.

If I remember correctly, the "No Auth Provider" is to do with the docker configuration. Could you try rerunning these commands?

`gcloud auth application-default login; gcloud auth configure-docker`

Comment: PS. I just fixed a build failure (Maven switched off insecure HTTP), so make sure to `git pull` before trying again. https://github.com/googlecloudrobotics/core/commit/6e620646f168c817b8a9642cc75288e9f6e1e3d7

Comment: I did trace some more in source code, in the middle of deploy.sh did I find likely one of reason which was "kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jetstack/cert-manager/${cert_manager_version}/deploy/manifests/00-crds.yaml"

- In my case below command :
~/workspace/core$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jetstack/cert-manager/v0.8.1/deploy/manifests/00-crds.yaml

error: No Auth Provider found for name "gcp"

Comment: And one more question here
Q: what does it mean and how to do about "Maven switched off insecure HTTP" you mentioned ?

Comment: Thanks for working that out. `gcloud container clusters get-credentials cloud-robotics` should create the GCP auth provider for `kubectl`, but obviously something went wrong. This could be related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/59259960/20330. Could you post the output of `gcloud version`? Re: Maven, you don't need to do anything except update the source code with `git pull`.

Comment: The version is the following info after typing the command : $gcloud version.

Google Cloud SDK 276.0.0
bq 2.0.52
core 2020.01.10
gsutil 4.47

Hopfully it could help you to find the right reason.

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately I wasn't able to reproduce, even using an Ubuntu 18 container and the same version of gcloud. I don't have any ideas left for what could have gone wrong. If you're keen to figure it out, all I could suggest is rerunning commands like `gcloud init`, `gcloud auth configure-docker`, `gcloud container clusters get-credentials cloud-robotics` until `kubectl get pods` (or similar) starts to work, at which point `deploy.sh` should work...

Comment: Thanks a lot - and the following build command made a bit confused. is it correct?
```
bazel build //...
```
this was step 4 in "https://googlecloudrobotics.github.io/core/how-to/deploy-from-sources"